# Angular 2 - Content not loading in router outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm still pretty new to Angular 2, hopefully you guys can help me out.

I have a fairly simple app, there's a login page, after successful login the user is directed to a page with a sidemenu. The login screen doesn't have this sidemenu. When the user logs out he is directed to the login page again.

The problem is that after login the sidemenu becomes visible but the other content is only visible after a refresh. Same thing for logout, after logout the page is blank, only after refresh the content (login page) is displayed. I'm probably doing something wrong but even after looking at other questions I can't figure it out.

Here's my routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfileComponent } from './profile-component/profile-component.component'
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LoggedInGuard } from './logged-in/logged-in.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [LoggedInGuard]},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The `LoginComponent`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {LoginService} from '../login-service/login-service.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  providers: [ LoginService ]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  error: String;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private loginService: LoginService,
              private router: Router) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
    }
    this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  login(): void {
    let self = this;
    this.loginService.login(this.loginForm.value.username, this.loginForm.value.password).subscribe(function (result) {
      if (result) {
        self.router.navigate(['/profile']);
      }

    }, function (error) {
      self.error = 'Invalid';
    });
  }
}
```

The `AppComponent` HTML looks like this:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary" *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
  <span>Sporter volgsysteem</span>
</md-toolbar>

<md-sidenav-layout *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
  <md-sidenav #start mode="side" [opened]="true">
      <a routerLink="/add" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary" disabled="false"><md-icon class="icon">add</md-icon><span class="nav-item">Toevoegen</span></a>
      <a routerLink="/compare" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary"><md-icon class="icon">swap_horiz</md-icon><span class="nav-item">Vergelijken</span></a>
      <a routerLink="/search" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary"><md-icon class="icon">search</md-icon><span class="nav-item">Zoeken</span></a>
      <a routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary"><md-icon class="icon">account_box</md-icon><span class="nav-item">Profiel</span></a>
      <a routerLink="/feedback" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary"><md-icon class="icon">feedback</md-icon><span class="nav-item">Feedback</span></a>
      <a routerLink="/faq" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary"><md-icon class="icon">info</md-icon><span class="nav-item">FAQ</span></a>

      <div class="spacer"></div>

      <a md-button color="primary" routerLink="/login" (click)="logout()"><md-icon class="icon">exit_to_app</md-icon><span class="nav-item">Uitloggen</span></a>
  </md-sidenav>


  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-layout>


<router-outlet *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()"></router-outlet>
```

`AppComponent`:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from "./login-service/login-service.service";
import {Router } from '@angular/router'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private loginService : LoginService,
              private router: Router) {
  }

  logout() {
    this.loginService.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loginService.isLoggedIn();
  }

}
```

So why isn't the content of the `ProfileComponent` displaying after login, and why isn't the login page displaying after logout, but both display when you refresh?

**Update**

Most suggested that it is due to multiple unnamed `router-outlet`s so to verify that I removed one of the outlets and show the sidemenu layout all the time. For testing purposes of course. That doesn't solve the problem, it gives me the same behaviour: the profile content is only loaded after refresh.

**Update 2**
I'm guessing this is related to using `*ngIf` to display the `router-outlet`

Comment: Your `AppComponent` has 2 `<router-outlet>` and both don't have a `name="xxx"`. Only one unnamed router-outlet per route is allowed.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Even though only 1 will be visible due to `*ngIf` ? I get no errors in the console.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the first `*ngIf`.

Comment: I still believe the issue is the double router-outlet.  It would probably be simpler to extrapolate that display-logic into separate components with their own routes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the comments above from @bhetzie and @jaime-torres and my own hypothesis I investigated further.
It turns out that the problem is indeed with the double `router-outlet`.

My solution was to extract a `LoginModule` module and then in that module redirect to the login page. In all other cases I route to yet another module called `SvsModule` which displays the logged in content with a side nav structure.

So the `SvsModule` has the following routing:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {path: 'svs', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[LoggedInGuard]},
  {path: 'svs/profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[LoggedInGuard]}
])
```

And the ProfileComponent uses the following HTML:

```
<md-sidenav-layout>
  <md-sidenav #start mode="side" [opened]="true">
    <md-nav-list>
      <a routerLink="/add" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary" disabled="false">
        <md-icon class="icon">add</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">Toevoegen</span>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/compare" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary">
        <md-icon class="icon">swap_horiz</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">Vergelijken</span>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/search" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary">
        <md-icon class="icon">search</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">Zoeken</span>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary">
        <md-icon class="icon">account_box</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">Profiel</span>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/feedback" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary">
        <md-icon class="icon">feedback</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">Feedback</span>
      </a>
      <a routerLink="/faq" routerLinkActive="active" md-button color="primary">
        <md-icon class="icon">info</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">FAQ</span>
      </a>

      <div class="spacer"></div>

      <a md-button color="primary" routerLink="/login" (click)="logout()">
        <md-icon class="icon">exit_to_app</md-icon>
        <span class="nav-item">Uitloggen</span></a>
    </md-nav-list>

  </md-sidenav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</md-sidenav-layout>
```

I will accept this as the answer, but thanks to aforementioned users to help me on my path.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is the double router-outlet as the comments above suggest. I did something like this in my project.

This was my solution:

I first created a service to determine the state of the login (I realize that event emitter is not good practice, I'm working on changing this to a behavior subject):

**GlobalEventsManager**

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class GlobalEventsManager {
     public showNavBar: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();



}
```

I used an authguard for my routes that checks if the login token is not expired. I used the angular2-jwt library for this

**AuthGuard**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from './GlobalEventsManager';


    @Injectable()
    export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

        constructor(private router: Router, private globaleventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) {}
        canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                    state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        if (tokenNotExpired('currentUser')) {
            this.globaleventsManager.showNavBar.emit(true);
            return true;

        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }

        }


    }
```

When a user logs in using my login component, I set the GlobalEventsManager to true

**Login**

```
constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private globaleventsManager: GlobalEventsManager) { }

ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status

        this.authenticationService.logout();
        this.globaleventsManager.showNavBar.emit(false);
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
            .subscribe( (result) => {
                this.globaleventsManager.showNavBar.emit(true);
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

In my navbar I subscribe to the GlobalEventsManager and set a boolean property to the result:

**Navbar**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavActiveService } from '../../../services/navactive.service';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from '../../../services/GlobalEventsManager';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls:['navbar.component.css'],  
})
export class NavComponent {
  showNavBar: boolean = true;

  constructor(private router: Router,              
              private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager){

    this.globalEventsManager.showNavBar.subscribe((mode:boolean)=>{
      this.showNavBar = mode;
    });

  }

}
```

In my navbar HTML I can now create two navbars, one navbar simply has a login nav and when my authguard notices that a toekn is expired or a user is not logged in it displays the navbar with just login as an option. Once logged in, the GlobalEventsManager value changes and my logged in navbar is displayed:

**Navbar HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="showNavBar">
//My logged in navbar 
</div>
<div *ngIf="!showNavBar">
//navbar that just displays login as an option
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work for you if you put the `router-outlet`s inside the divs (so two in total)? I tried this, but I think the problem is caused by the `*ngIf` the digest is already done and then the `router-outlet` is added to the DOM. Or something like that That's what I think now at least

Comment: You should only ever have just the one router-outlet. I think that's the issue as you just suggested

Comment: I had exactly same issue, I'm using multiple router-outlets, and that's not the main issue, but the *ngIf used to hide temporarly the inner router-outlet wrapper was the culprit. I'll need to change the logic there only to hide instead of wait to render the html.

Answer (score 1):

Put your navigate call in a [ngZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone). (Angular 5)

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private router: Router
) {}

...

this.ngZone.run( () => {
    this.router.navigate(['/profile']);
});
```